# background and toolbar apear sometimes xamarin forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, layout, xamarin.forms

I have this page in xamarin.forms
the problem is: mainly when it's the first time that the device is opened, My first page is bad loaded and I don't know why

this is the xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="neoFly_Montana.Views.Splash2"
         BackgroundImage="Abertura.jpg"
         NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False">
<ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

The background is not loaded and I have a blank screen, and the HasNavigationBar="False" doesn't work...and a toolbar appears...but, always in the first time that the app is oppened...I don't understand that...

Comment: Are you using MasterDetailPage? How you navigate to this page?

Comment: Your question is not clear. If your talking about image background, you should place your background image in Resource folder in both Android and iOS project.

Comment: @SandeshAcharya LOL u are right, I was crazy when I wrote that!

Comment: @ZiyadGodil I am not using masterDetail